# Select a table which is created dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table dc201709 which is created dynmacially on every 1st of the month. So if its October it will be 201710 and so on.

DC is the prefix and 201709 is current year and month in yyyymm format

Table look like

ID  Name    Classs

1   ABC First
2   LMN second

I want to select only ID and Class from the above table.

which I can achieve from the below query

```
select ID,Class from dc201709
```

Now I want to make the select statement such that I dont want to hardcode the table name again on every 1st day of a month

something like :-

```
select ID,Class from dc+CONVERT(varchar(6),getdate(),112)
```

so that I dont want to change my select statement again and again.

Is there a way to achieve that?

When I try:

```
select * from dc+'CONVERT(varchar(6),getdate(),112)' It gives me an error
```

Incorrect syntax

Comment: Not an answer, but is there a reason why you want separate tables for each month?  This could make reporting a bit onerous, and I would personally much rather have a single table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use exec statement

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(200)
SET @str  = 'select ID, Class from dc'+ CONVERT(varchar(6),getdate(),112)
exec(@str)
```